# Celery sending tasks but not executing them

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery

I've a currently running setup of Django 1.11.15, Celery 4.2 and Redis 4.0.2 on `docker-compose` and I detected that my periodic tasks are being properly sent by celerybeat but it seems the worker isn't running them.

A simple test task:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from turnapp.celery import app

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task
def say_hello():
    print("HELLO!")
    logger.info("HELLO!")
    return "HELLO!"
```

Which I configured to run every one minute. The task is loaded and gets send every one minute, but it never runs (because I don't see the `HELLO!` string on my output):

```
celeryworkerdev_1  | [2018-08-10 19:06:32,229: INFO/MainProcess] default@8516f3a70571 ready.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:08:30,044: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:08:35,051: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:08:40,060: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:08:45,069: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:08:50,077: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celeryworkerdev_1  | [2018-08-10 19:06:32,230: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->4
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:08:55,084: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 4.91 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:00,001: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task gymnasium_say-hello (gymnasium.say_hello)
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:00,002: DEBUG/MainProcess] gymnasium.say_hello sent. id->ef0a2715-185e-49da-89a0-a9f65b4ed05a
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:00,003: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:05,010: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:10,019: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:15,024: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:20,032: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:25,038: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:30,045: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:35,052: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:35,053: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:35,071: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:40,077: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:45,083: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:50,089: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:09:55,097: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 4.89 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:10:00,001: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task gymnasium_say-hello (gymnasium.say_hello)
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:10:00,006: DEBUG/MainProcess] gymnasium.say_hello sent. id->a3085879-4f27-415e-8683-aeea42fb15de
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:10:00,007: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
celerybeatdev_1    | [2018-08-10 19:10:05,015: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
```

I get no errors anywhere. Worker, Beat and Redis get started and display the loaded tasks fine. Here are my settings:

```
CELERY_REDIS_HOSTNAME = env.get(
    'CELERY_REDIS_HOSTNAME',
    default='broker-master'
)
CELERY_REDIS_PORT = env.get('CELERY_REDIS_PORT', default=6379)
CELERY_REDIS_DB = env.get('CELERY_REDIS_DB', default=0)
CELERY_BROKER_URL = env.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', default='')

if not CELERY_BROKER_URL:
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://{hostname}:{port}/{db}'.format(
       hostname=CELERY_REDIS_HOSTNAME,
       port=CELERY_REDIS_PORT,
       db=CELERY_REDIS_DB
    )

CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10

CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default')
)

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_PUBLISH_RETRY = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = False

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's how I start celery worker and beat:

`celery worker -A turnapp -Q default -n default@%h -l DEBUG`

`celery beat -A turnapp -l INFO -S django --loglevel=debug`

Comment: Does it work when you're not using docker?

Comment: @sP_ locally I use docker-compose for development and on deployment I use Kubernetes. On both occasions it doesn't work. I found this bug https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3759 which I think it's relevant

Comment: try to remove all settings that are not required, specialy the one with routing key, celery uses default values that works and you overriding them improperly might be the cause of the problem... also try to start the celery worker with `-B` to see if the task get executed correctly

Comment: @MazelTov thanks! I've tried disabling all settings and also using `-B` instead of running a separated `celery beat` instance. Still no luck!

Comment: how do you start celery worker, how do you start beat, can you explore redis that after beat scheduled the task it is really there (try without celery worker first), for example with [rediscommander](https://github.com/joeferner/redis-commander)

Comment: What's the output of `celery -A turnapp inspect registered`

Comment: @MarianoBaragiola any update on this. Were you able to find and fix this issue?